# Excel: if this cell=value format all rows with matching ID

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have data like the following:

```
ID  Action
3   G
1   D
2   X
1   P
3   E
2   M
3   B
```

When I enter a `B` in the `Action` column, I want to find all rows that have the same ID as the row where `B` was entered.  In the example above I entered `B` in the last row, so I want to select all rows that have an ID of `3` (to match the ID of the row where `B` was entered).  I then want to format those rows (change the text color for example).  In this case, the following rows would be formatted:

```
3   G
3   E
3   B
```

I may also change values in the `Action` column any time in the future, for example if I change `X` to `B` in the example above, then all rows with an ID of `2` will be affected:

```
2   B
2   M
```

The existing rows with an ID of `3` will retain their formatting (because one of the rows with an ID of `3` has a `B` in the `Action` column.

In the example above, rows with an ID of `1` are not affected (because none of them have a `B` in the `Action` column).

Is this possible?

Comment: My be possible if you create user-defined function by VBA.  There is many unclear things in your question, for example where are you think the place for input data in folloging phrase "enter a B in any row".

Comment: Yes @pnuts, all rows that have a matching ID should be formatted.

Comment: @Fumu7, normally the 'Action' would be a new entry on a blank row, but I may want to change the 'Action' in an existing row above by changing for example an 'X' to a 'B'.  Then I want to format all rows with the same ID as the row I just modified.  I am a programmer (but do not know VBA) so a quick example of how to create and use VBA may help.

Comment: @pnuts, I just realized; I meant enter a 'B' in the 'Action column' of any row.

Comment: When you change X to B, what do you expect? ID corresponding to B in third data is 2 and That corresponding to B in seventh data is 3. To change format of 1st,3rd,5th,6th and 7th rows is what do you want??   You should explain your problem more cleary and exactly.

Comment: @Fumu7, I changed the question to explain the problem more clearly; note I have an answer now from pnuts.

Comment: Can anyone tell my why this question is being voted down?  I thought the question was clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=$A1=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("B",$B:$B,0))
```

with Applies to of `=$A:$H` or change `H` to suit.

Comment: With a little tweaking for my specific worksheet, this answered my question.  My actual formula is: `=$A2=INDEX($A2:$A500,MATCH("DIS",$C2:$C500,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting with the format based on a formula. The formula should be a comparison between the ID alongside the location of your "B" (use INDEX() with MATCH()) and the value in the cell being formatted. Something like:

= IF(cell_value = INDEX(ID_range, MATCH("B", Action_range, 0), 0), TRUE, FALSE)

If this returns true, set the formatting as you please, then use the Conditional Formatting manager to extend the 'formula' over your entire range.

Comment: Right you are pnuts, I just wanted to make it obvious how the formula works.